# What is the best way to pass data between components in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

Suppose I have an `App.vue`. `Query.vue` and `Result.vue` are its children.

And the router looks like this:

```
import Query from '@/components/Query'
import Result from '@/components/Result'

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'query',
      component: Query
    }, {
      path: '/result',
      name: 'result',
      component: Result
    }
  ]
})
```

There is a button in `Query.vue`, when clicked, it will send a `POST` request to API:

```
  this.$http.post(url, {
    arg1: arg1,
    arg2: arg2
  }).then(function (response) {
    data = response.data

    // I want to do something like:
    this.$router.push({path: 'result', payload: data})

  }, function (response) {})
```

And then in `Query.vue`, I can handle the `payload`.

But it seems not possible. Should I use `store` to make it?

```
  this.$http.post(url, {
    data: "some data"
  }).then(function (response) {
    store.store(response.data)
    this.$router.push({path: 'result'})
  }, function (response) {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you need just to pass some data one directional from parent to child - USE PROPS.
2. If you need to pass data from child to parent - USE EVENTS
3. If you need to keep some data synced across many components (not parent/child) - USE VUEX

Comment: I need just to pass some data one directional, but the `Result.vue` is not the child of  `Query.vue`. So use `vuex`?

Comment: Yes. It will be the best way and recommended by Vue

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!